# How to query oracle dates properly?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from mytable where datecolumn == to_date('01-DEC-13','DD-MMM-YY')
```

I am getting the "ORA-01821: date format not recognized"

Where I do a query for a select * from mytable, I see that the values in datecolumn show up like "01-DEC-13" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does Oracle use `==`?

Comment: just simply change "MMM" to "MON". I don't think oracle to_date support "MMM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're 100% sure you will never ever use different language settings, I'd recommend using MM instead of MON:

```
select * from mytable where datecolumn = to_date('2013-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

This will work with any NLS settings, whereas comparing the output of to_date(...MON...) with 'DEC' will fail utterly on different locales.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using the full century for dates. I've dealt with plenty of databases where somebody messed up the centuries because they didn't understand Oracle or the front-end language. Consider this for your `01-DEC-13` date:

```
CREATE TABLE LousyDates (DateVal DATE);
INSERT INTO LousyDates VALUES (DATE '2013-12-01');
INSERT INTO LousyDates VALUES (DATE '1713-12-01');
INSERT INTO LousyDates VALUES (TO_DATE('12/1/13 BC', 'MM/DD/YYYY BC'));

SELECT
  TO_CHAR(DateVal, 'DD-MON-YY') AS NoCentury,
  TO_CHAR(DateVal, 'MM/DD/YYYY BC') AS WithCentury
FROM LousyDates;

NOCENTURY          WITHCENTURY
------------------ -------------
01-DEC-13          12/01/2013 AD
01-DEC-13          12/01/1713 AD
01-DEC-13          12/01/0013 BC
```

OK, maybe I'm overstating the point with the 13 BC date, but you get the idea :)

To use the century...

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE datecolumn = TO_DATE('01-DEC-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE datecolumn = DATE '2013-12-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * from MYTABLE WHERE TO_CHAR(datecolumn,'DD-MON-YY') == '01-DEC-13'
```

instead of converting your wildcard, try to convert your datetime.

Comment: This will render any indices on datecolumn useless (unless you are using a function-based index). Doing it the other way round (converting the argument) is much more sensible.